# How can I tell jruby-jars to use a patched version of JRuby?

Tags: jruby, warbler

In my rather unique application needs, I've had to make a patch to JRuby-1.7.26.   However, I've learned that Warbler (that uses jruby-jars) embeds it's own copy of JRuby into my lib/ directory.   How can I configure either Warbler or jruby-jars to consider my patch when it compiles JRuby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to build a custom version of *jruby-jars* gem (from the JRuby source)

and then specify that version to be used in the *Gemfile* :

```
 gem 'jruby-jars', '1.7.26.PATCH', require: false
```